# Packaged Flash in Phonegap framework

Tags: ios, flash, cordova

I develop my game in Flash, but Phonegap has a great UI framework for applications that Flash simply does not have, is it possible to package my game using the flash iPhone packager, extracting the payload and using it in my Phonegap application? Anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Flash puts it in some sort of iOS binary file, I highly doubt you can extract html/JavaScript from that.

You would have to convert your actionscript to HTML / Javascript and store all your assets as files.

If you don't want to do that entirely from scratch try [Gordon](http://paulirish.com/work/gordon/demos/), there might be a way to look at the generated JavaScript.

Comment: My previous experience of HTML5 and javascript is that it can't play sound and manipulate assets efficiently enough to create games. Lot's of lag on IOS.